# Generate a matrix with certain values such that its standard deviation is 1?

Tags: r

I'm currently going through an 'Introduction to R' book and I am completely stuck at the following question:

> Create a 5x5 matrix (M), all its entries drawn from the uniform distribution, with sd 1 and mean being the column number of the element. (so mean(matrix[,I]) == column(i), sd(matrix) == 1)

I have to make use of the `sapply()` function.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
m <- matrix(runif(25), nrow = 5, ncol = 50
sapply(matrix, function(x) sd(x) == 1)
```

But that part already doesn't work and I'm just stuck.
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: As is you have a syntax error. Looks like you have a 0 instead of a closed parentheses. In addition please expand on your problem. What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting an error message? What else have you tried?

Comment: @OTStats It's just some stupid start I make but I don't think this is the way it should be done. It's more to show I really don't know where to start, than it being a good example of what the answer should be. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: For classification, does `sd = 1` mean that the sd of total 25 numbers is 1, or that sd of every column is 1?

Comment: @DarrenTsai The sd of the total numbers needs to be 1, the mean of each column should equal the column number.

Comment: I found that you cannot make the sd of total numbers be 1. For example, `m <- matrix(rep(1:5, each = 5), 5, 5)`. This example is the most extreme situation that every column has no variation, i.e. `sd = 0`, and it is still a uniform distrbution. You can check `apply(m, 2, sd)`. And then you use `sd(m)` to check total sd, it's 1.44. It is unlikely to be lower to 1.

Answer (score 2):

The mean can be set by the following:

```
my_uniform <- function(col_nbr) {
  runif(5, min = col_nbr-sqrt(12)/2, max=col_nbr+sqrt(12)/2)
}

M <- sapply(1:5, my_uniform)
```

This will lead to std=1 for each column and the mean is set to the number of column in each column. The formular for mean is:

[image: mean]

The formular for the sdt is:

[image: std]

Comment: How did you come up with the idea of subtracting sqrt(12)/2? Is that some sort of famous equation?

Comment: The sd of the total numbers needs to be 1, the mean of each column should equal the column number, so this won't work, sorry for not putting it properly in my question

Comment: It's a good idea. I know you use the variance formula of uniform distribution, i.e. `(max - min)^2 / 12 = 1`. Maybe you can explain this for who haven't learned it.

Comment: I've just edited the question so it's easier to understand. It should me mean(matrix[,I]) == colnum(i), sd(matrix) == 1

Comment: Ok. This includes some math here. You will have a std of 1 and your mean should be the column number. So you need to set your max and min such that both conditions are satisfied. What i have done is to set max = column_number + c and min = column_number  - c. Now your mean condition is satisfied.To get the c you have your fist condition which is std=1. This will lead to a formula for c which is c=sqrt(12)/2

Answer (score 0):

This should now be the correct way to define the uniform distribution. If the mean is defined as `mean=0.5*(a+b)` then defining the upper limit like this will result in a mean of the column number.

```
 sapply(1:5, function(x){runif(5, min = 0, max = x*2)})
```

See this little MonteCarlo experiment:

```
mean(runif(50000, min = 0, max = 1*2))
```

Comment: That does generate a 5x5 matrix with sd 1, but how would I make it so that the mean of each column is the column number of the element? (e.g., the first column has to be values like 0.5 and 1.5 for a 2x2 matrix because then the mean of the first column is 1)

Comment: I think the issue is that you have random numbers, so the mean will only be equal to the column number if the random numbers go to infinity, so by definition in such a small sample there are deviations.

Comment: This code does work correctly for the mean. I was also thinking, the sd of a unit distribution is always 1, so can't I just ignore that part?

Answer (score 0):

From the random uniform distribution one can only simulate values between a range with the same probability each one, being the expected mean when n goes to infinity to be the mean value between the min and the max. 
From the point of view of a uniform distribution, the mean and the standard deviation cannot be defined in the function. What you can do is simulate such that the middle value (i.e. the mean) would be the number you are expecting, but the standard deviation would not be 1:

```
set.seed(1)

numrow<-5
numcol<-5
Mat<-matrix(NA, nrow = numrow, ncol = numcol)
for(i in 1:numcol){
  Mat[,i]<- runif(numrow, min = i-0.5, max = i+0.5)
}
Mat

# [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] 0.7655087 2.398390 2.705975 3.997699 5.434705
# [2,] 0.8721239 2.444675 2.676557 4.217619 4.712143
# [3,] 1.0728534 2.160798 3.187023 4.491906 5.151674
# [4,] 1.4082078 2.129114 2.884104 3.880035 4.625555
# [5,] 0.7016819 1.561786 3.269841 4.277445 4.767221
```

To see the formulas of the expected mean and expected variance (therefore the standard deviation) I refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Answer (score 0):

You gotta find the pdf ranges (a, b) that fit each mean, sd pair first.  The mean of a uniform dist is

- mu <- (b + a) / 2 The mu values are indexed from 1:5.
- The sd of a uniform dist is (b - a) / sqrt(12)
- The sd is fixed at 1, so use the sd equation to solve for b.
- Then plug in b in the mu equation to solve for a
- Now you have the a, b parameters of the uniform dist
- The sapply function then looks like this:

  z <- sapply(1:5, function(x) runif(5, 2*x - (2*x + sqrt(12)/2), (2*x + sqrt(12)/2)))

Run `summary(z)` will give you the output stats.  Because of the small sample size the sample means will be off.  To test, change the runif sample size from 5 to 100000.  Then run `summary(z)` again.  You will see that the values converge to the index means.